# Hierarchial deletion of tables in SQL Server 2008 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `ParentTable` in which I have `parentId` as primary key.

Now I have three child tables `ChildTable1`, `ChildTable2` and `ChildTable3`.

- in `ChildTable1`, primary key is `ch1Id` and foreign key is `fkparentId` (pk from `ParentTable`)
- in `ChildTable2`, primary key is `ch2Id` and foreign keys are `fkparentId` and `fkch1Id` (primary key from `ChildTable1`)
- in `ChildTable3`, primary key is `ch3Id` and foreign keys are `fkparentId, fkch1Id` and `fkch2Id` (primary key from `ChildTable2`).

And this goes on..

I want to write a query to delete these tables hierarchially in the following manner.

First delete `ChildTable3` > then delete `ChildTable2` > then delete `ChildTable1` and finally delete `ParentTable`.

I have a vague idea of doing this like

```
delete from ChildTable3
where fkch2Id = ch2.ch2Id
and fkch1Id = ch1.ch1Id
and fkparentId = p.parentId
```

then proceeding to ChildTable2 for deletion and so on. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: What rows from ChildTable3 do you want to delete? All rows? Rows that meet some condition in ChildTable3 or rows that meet some condition in some other table?

Comment: I want to delete All Rows from ChildTable3 and other tables mentioned.

Comment: Then you only need to do `delete from ChildTable3` followed by `delete from ChildTable2` etc and finally you do `delete from ParentTable`. No need to join to other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do same thing without any query by setting `cascade on delete` on foreign key definitin.

if you don't set foreign key definiton on db you can delete records on `fkparentId` like this.

```
declare @parentId int = 3

delete from ChildTable3 where fkparentId = @parentId;
delete from ChildTable2 where fkparentId = @parentId;
delete from ChildTable1 where fkparentId = @parentId;
delete from ParentTable where parentId = @parentId;
```